# How to configure elastic search correct on Shopware 6?

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to set up elastic search on our server. Actually it seems to work, but when i run the product importer (own plugin), then it has exceptions.

So the config is done like described in the documentation: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/enterprise-extensions/enterprise-search?category=shopware-6-en/enterprise-extensions

But even if all product fields are set to "Not searched" in the settings, the importer runs into this exception:

```
ERROR     [app] object mapping for [customFields.product_processing_fields] tried to parse field [product_processing_fields] as object, but found a concrete value
```

```
In ElasticsearchIndexer.php line 210:
                                                                                                  
  [Shopware\Elasticsearch\Exception\ElasticsearchIndexingException]                               
  Following errors occurred while indexing:                                                       
  object mapping for [customFields.product_processing_fields] tried to parse field [product_proc  
  essing_fields] as object, but found a concrete value
```

If i turn off elastic search in the .env file, then the importer runs trough without any issue.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the custom field does not correlate to what type it was configured as. Check the `type` property of the `config` column in the `custom_field` table. If it is `bool` then the value mustn't be a string for example. You can see where the type is mapped from what is set in your custom field's config to what Elasticsearch will expect by looking at the method `CustomFieldUpdater::getTypeFromCustomFieldType`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I checked and it was indeed json instead text (although json would makes more sense). So i changed it, but the error remains.

Comment: Did you change the value in both columns `type` and `config` of the table `custom_field`? The `config` column should contain json that also has a type property. If the value is supposed to be string then both should be set to `text`.

Comment: Since this effectively changes the mapping it probably is a good idea to run `bin/console es:reset` followed by `bin/console es:index`.  This might fix things.

Comment: Something else: when i go to the category page, i get this error: Typed property Shopware\Elasticsearch\Framework\ElasticsearchHelper::$logger must not be accessed before initialization.
Any suggestions how to solve that?